# multiline regexp matching in bash

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

I would like to do some multiline matching with bash's `=~`

```
#!/bin/bash
str='foo = 1 2 3
bar = what about 42?
boo = more words
'
re='bar = (.*)'
if [[ "$str" =~ $re ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
        echo no match
fi
```

Almost there, but if I use `^` or `$`, it will not match, and if I don't use them, `.` eats newlines too.

EDIT:

sorry, values after `=` could be multi-word values.

Comment: don't forget to accept answers that solve your question. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I could be wrong, but after a quick read from [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17000.html), especially Note 2 at the end of the page, bash can sometimes include the newline character when matching with the dot operator. Therefore, a quick solution would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
str='foo = 1
bar = 2
boo = 3
'
re='bar = ([^\
]*)'
if [[ "$str" =~ $re ]]; then
        echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
        echo no match
fi
```

Notice that I now ask it match anything except newlines. Hope this helps =)

Edit: Also, if I understood correctly, the ^ or $ will actually match the start or the end (respectively) of the string, and not the line. It would be better if someone else could confirm this, but it is the case and you do want to match by line, you'll need to write a while loop to read each line individually.

Comment: Should also work without the backslash, or mixing quotes: `re='bar = ([^'$'\n'']*)'`

Comment: Thanks for the observation! =)

Comment: @l0b0: huh, `'$'\n''` stands for a newline?

Comment: Yes, $'...' is a way to quote characters in the ANSI C notation. Here is a reference from the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html =)

Comment: @pihentagy There are [many ways to quote strings in Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use newlines in a re to match in multiline strings:

```
s=$'aa\nbb\ncc'
nl=$'\n'
if [[ $s =~ (^|$nl)cc($|$nl) ]]; then
    echo found
fi
```